# Javascript unrecognized expression

Tags: javascript, regex

i have complex element attributes like

> CS::@station1/cs1_station-0/be/PA300___(1)#22

I tried to remove all expressions with this regex

```
/[/\@\/\_\/\#\/\:\/\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g
```

but i get exceptions like:

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #OS::@station1\cs-0...

Has somebody a regex to escape all unrecognized js expressions?

Comment: Oh, just escape the `/`s in the pattern. Do you mean `/[@\/_#\\:\-\[\]{}()*+?.^$|]/g`?

Comment: ...especially the first one...and don't escape characters that don't need escaping. My eyes hurt.

Comment: Thank @stribizhev this regex works fine.

Comment: Tim has already posted it. I think you can accept his answer. Although I hate answers with "Try <code>" or "This should probably help: <CODE>".. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/[/\@\/\_\/\#\/\:\/\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g
```

should probably be

```
/[-\/@_#:[\]{}()*+?.\\^$|]+/g
```

Comment: Hi. I have a new Error:
`Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #CS\::@station14\_test\_string\-0`
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, no - the regex would have matched all the special characters in that string...

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a negated character class may be useful:

```
var s = 'CS::@station1/cs1_station-0/be/PA300___(1)#22';

console.log(s.replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/gi, ''));
```